# how to compare negative floating points in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

We tested our script and it fails on negative floating points comparison in bash.
What are we doing wrong ?

```
$F1=10000000000
$F2=300
FLP=$(bc <<< "scale=5; ($F2 - $F1)/$F2 * 100")
if [ $FLP -eq "1" ]; then
    echo " greater"
else
    echo "smaller"
fi
```

It keeps printing "greater" with -99.99900

Thanks all for help

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

F1=$1
F2=$2
FLP=$(bc <<< "scale=5; (${F2} - ${F1})/${F2} * 100")

if (( $(echo "${FLP} 1" | awk '{print ($1 > $2)}') )); then
  echo "greater"
else
  echo "smaller"
 fi
```

Adopted from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237794/how-to-compare-two-decimal-numbers-in-bash-awk

Answer (score 0):

Bash help for `-eq` states that it compares `INTEGER` types. There is no floating point support in `[`.

What I'd recommend is that you're already using `bc` to do the calculation -- why don't you use `bc` also to do the comparison? As in, instead of `if A < B`, you could test for `if B-A > 0`, where the subtraction is done by `bc`, and the signal check be easily done in bash.